# Setup SMTP connection between mautic and iRedMail

Tags: smtp, email-server, ubuntu-16.04, smtp-auth, iredmail

I have set up my iRedMail on AWS EC2 small instance, now everything is working fine under port 25, but I need to authenticate users to authenticate themselves.

In mautic "*to authenticate we need following:*"

[image: Credentials need to authenticate user]

I have created new user and password in iRedMail admin panel, but if I try to authenticate using that username an password in mautic its showing below error

```
**Connection could not be established with host ec2-54-169-33-216.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Connection timed out #110] Log data: ++ Starting Swift_SmtpTransport !! The connection could not be established with host ec2-54-169-33-216.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Connection timed out #110] (code: 0)
++ Starting Swift_SmtpTransport !! Connection could not be established with host ec2-54-169-33-216.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Connection timed out #110] (code: 0)**
```

Is there anything I need to change in postfix's main.cf?

Comment: Did you open the necessary ports in your security group?

Comment: Really? Which ports did you open?

Comment: https://imgur.com/VGhxuTZ these are the ports I have opened these ports

Comment: Those are _outbound_ rules. You are trying to make a connection _inbound_ to an instance!

Comment: sorry michael, i have no idea about these, coz this is the first time i am working on it so, the thing is i have to send the mails from my application throufgh iRedMails to my contacts, how can i do it ??

Comment: Hi @Michael, Thank you very much, coz of you asking me about security groups I rechecked it again and added 587 port. and now it's working fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Port 25 is blocked in AWS. Try switching to another VPS. That is the only solution!